# Will apache2 restart automatically if it's processes die on the server?

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2

Will apache2 restart automatically if it's processes die on the server?

As I understand it, apache2 starts by using SysV with links in `/etc/rc?.d/`.

I can see them using this command:
`ls -l /etc/rc?.d/*apache2`

But will apache2 restart automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if Apache hangs or exits for some reason (eg. segmentation fault) it will not come back from the dead on its own.

Even though I never experienced such situations myself (Apache being the most reliable HTTP server I ever worked with) it can happen. There are a good deal of fixes for these problems out there. [This useful guide](http://www.m3rls.com/2008/02/automatically-monitor-and-restart-apache/) is particularly detailed, proposing a Cron timed solution with PHP and Curl to detect if Apache is up.